# Create a JPA Named Query with conditional where clause based on user value selections

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I am rewriting an existing application and am required to use the existing application queries using JPA 2.  How do I write a Named Query that replaces a dynamic query that will add sections to the where clause based on a value selection.  In other words, if a value is selected from a drop down box, I will add a AND/OR section to the where clause.  If not, that where clause section is omitted.  For example:

```
int paramIdx = 0;
String query = "SELECT * FROM ANIMAL_TABLE WHERE...something";
String whereClause = "";

if(canine!= null and canine.trim().length() > 0) {
    whereClause += " AND canine_type = :" + (paramIdx + 1) + viewObject.setWhereClauseParam(paramIdx, canine);
        paramIdx++;
}
if(cat != null and cat.trim().length() > 0) {
    whereClause += " AND cat_type = :" + (paramIdx + 1) + viewObject.setWhereClauseParam(paramIdx, cat);
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this using JPA.  Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Use two named queries, or generate a non-named query dynamically, or use the criteria API, or use QueryDSL.

Comment: I thought about creating multiple named queries, however I have 9 variables and the combination of each would mean that I would need to create each option as a named query.  Still, yes that's an option.  Creating dynamic native query would, based on what I've read, can be costly because they are typically not cached.  I'm not familiar with the criteria API.  Is that available though JEE7?

Comment: Caching of queries offers a really minor performance improvement. What matters is the execution of the query and the retrieval of the results. Use what makes the most sense, instead of choosing based on meaningless performance improvements. You need a dynamic query, so create a dynamic query. That's what the Criteria API is all about. Creating 2⁹ named queries is really not reasonable.

Comment: JB, just did some reading about the criteria API.  That would solve the problem I presented above, but not the real life situation that I need to solve.  I presented the example above to keep my question simple.  In this rewrite, one of my requirements is to re-use the complex queries from the previous implementation.  So, the criteria API will not work.  I believe my best plan of attack would be to use multiple named queries.  I appreciate your input.  It helped validate my direction.

Comment: I was responding the same time you were.  You offer some additional good advice.  It does make better sense to create a dynamic query and would satisfy my requirements of reuse.  Especially if the performance hit is minor.  Again, thanks very much for your help JB.